# telegram how to query telegram api to find channel/user?

Tags: api, telegram

I want to query telegram api in javascript to find channel/user.
But from their documentation I didn't find anything.

Is there something like `api.telegram.org/findchannel?token=MYTOKEN&query=channelName`.

I also search for javascript library but I didn't find anything too.
I don't think a bot is what I need. I just want to query telegram api to find channels/users